# Outputting data using a collection class PHP

Tags: php, collections

I have created a collection class and then a class car. I'm adding instances of the car class too the collection class. In my class car I can add a description, top speed ect to each car. I would like to be able to loop through all of the cars and output the description and top speed. Sorry for the a lot of code I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve. I have added a comment in the bottom code/class of where I would like to output these things.

Collection class:

```
<?php 
 class ObjectCollection  
{  
    //This is an array to hold line items
    private $items_array ;

    private $itemCounter; //Count the number of items

    public function __construct() {
        //Create an array object to hold line items
        $this->items_array = array();
        $this->itemCounter=0; 
     }

    public function getItemCount(){
        return $this->itemCounter;
    }  


    // This will add a new line object to line items array
    public function addItem($item) {
       $this->itemCounter++;
       $this->items_array[] = $item;
    }

}
?>
```

My Car Class:

```
class car {
  private $id;
  private $description;
  private $topspeed;
  private $price;

  public function __construct($id, $price) {
       $this->id = $id;
       $this->price = $price;
  }

  public function setDescription($description) {
            $this->description = $description ;
  }

  public function getDescription() {
      return $this->description ;
  }

  public function setTopspeed($topspeed) {
            $this->topspeed = $topspeed;
 }

public function getTopspeed() {
      return $this->topspeed ;
 }

 //other methods here

} //End of class

?>
```

CLASS where I'm looping through the `ObjectCollection`:

```
 $car = new car("1",400);
 $car2 = new car("2",4400);

 $car->setDescription("A really fast car ");
 $car2->setDescription("A really slow car ");



 $ObjColl = new ObjectCollection();
 $ObjColl->addItem($car1);
 $ObjColl->addItem($car2);



 for($i = 0;$ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){
   //CODE NEED TO BE ADDED TO OUTPUT TOPSPEED AND DESCRIPTION ECT????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add following method to ObjectCollection class to get access to items array:

```
public function getItems(){
    return $this->items_array;
}
```

Then you would be able to loop like the following code:

```
foreach ($ObjColl->getItems() as $item){
    if (is_a($item, 'car')){
        echo $item->getDescription();
    }
}
```